# Complex view logic in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I'm curious in my exploration of AngularJS.

Sometimes views are quite complex and the logic provided by CSS and Angular templates is not enough. For example, let's say that I want to add decorative elements whose number change according to an image size.

How should I implement it in AngularJS?

Comment: Implement what? Where is your code or issue?

Comment: @zvisofer please stop editing in backticks around language/library names like CSS and AngularJS. Most of the rest of the stuff you do in edits is good, as far as I can see, but wrapping technology names in backticks [is not an appropriate use of backticks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189099/should-this-particular-suggested-edit-which-i-think-adds-backticks-improperly).

Comment: @Dalorzo There was some introductory text in my question (I'll bring it back). This is a matter of sheer curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

Try to decompose views into directives. Directives play role of components in AngularJS.